# can't find variable: drawer_width

Tags: react-native

tried to create side menu in react native, got code from this url https://reactnativeexample.com/simple-lightweight-customisable-menu-drawer-component/

but when i run getting this error: can't find variable: drawer_width
i have tried a lot to solve it but not yet success

Please any one help me

Below is full codes

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'

import MenuDrawer from 'react-native-side-drawer'

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }

  toggleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
  };

  drawerContent = () => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleOpen} style={styles.animatedBox}>
        <Text>Close</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MenuDrawer 
          open={this.state.open} 
          drawerContent={this.drawerContent()}
          drawerPercentage={45}
          animationTime={250}
          overlay={true}
          opacity={0.4}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleOpen} style={styles.body}>
            <Text>Open</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </MenuDrawer>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginTop: 30,
    zIndex: 0
  },
  animatedBox: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#38C8EC",
    padding: 10
  },
  body: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F04812'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in [index.js](https://github.com/pedreviljoen/react-native-menu/blob/master/index.js) style sheet is not received DRAWER_WIDTH props
So you can copy this code and customize it and solve its problem

I suggest copy [index.js](https://github.com/pedreviljoen/react-native-menu/blob/master/index.js) and paste into you code and install [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) npm

You can replace drawerPercentage into hardcoded value as your requirement into whole code

```
const DRAWER_WIDTH = SCREEN_WIDTH * (drawerPercentage / 100)
```

This line write something like this

```
const DRAWER_WIDTH = SCREEN_WIDTH * (45 / 100)
```

Comment: My index.js like this

      
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

Comment: Then use this file as a component which is previous mention into web link which you share in post

Comment: after creating menuDrawer,js and import getting this error "undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this$props.drawerPercentage')

Comment: Please do not tire to help me